# Expectation Value Definition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, probability, normalization

I think I might just not be thinking things completely through here but
I've seen the expectation value of a Hermitian operator written in many sources as both $$\langle A \rangle=\frac{\langle\psi|A| \psi \rangle}{\langle\psi| \psi \rangle}$$ and $$\langle A \rangle=\langle\psi|A| \psi \rangle.$$ Are these the same? and if not, what exactly is the difference (other than just the fraction)?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is normalization.

In the first case, you consider a generic wave function $|\psi\rangle$ that is not necessarily normalized.

In the second case, you are considering a normalized wave function such that
$$\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 1$$